# silverlight nested bindings in usercontrol

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to bind a bindig example:

settings.xaml

```
<labels:KeyValueLabel Key="User name:" Label="{Binding Name}" Margin="10"/>
```

KeyValueLabel.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="rodzic.Controls.Labels.KeyValueLabel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="KeyLabel" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ValueLabel" Text="{Binding Label}"/>
</Grid>
```

KeyValueLabel.xaml.cs

```
public partial class KeyValueLabel : UserControl
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Label",
        typeof(String),
        typeof(KeyValueLabel),
        new PropertyMetadata("default", new PropertyChangedCallback(LabelChanged))
    );

    static void LabelChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //e is always being set to ""
    }

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public KeyValueLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

If I pass value as a static text in settings.xaml it works but binding data from settings.xaml don't for key nor for label.

How to fix label binding? I want to make it work no matter how nested the binding is.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to create a Custom Control, not  UserControl.  These are two completely different things.  With a custom control, you can create your dependency properties and then bind to them directly like you would any other control.

In the custom control, you then catch the setting of it and set the Text property of the TextBlock directly.  Thus you don't need the double binding.

Comment: the problem is with DataContext, in the parent page settings.xaml it is set to this and KeyValueLabel always try to bind Label property from settings.xaml even though i set DataContext in KeyValueLabel

Comment: I understand that it is a usercontrol.  What I am saying is that you should try to achieve it by creating a "Custom Control", not a "UserControl" because you can do much more with it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278068(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I achived my goal by doing something completly different and i will check custom control as soon as I'll have some more free time to experiment :) thx for the tip!

Comment: Your welcome.  Don't forget to mark as answered, if the question has been answered.

Comment: it is not answered :) I'm super curious how to make it in silverlight it is possible in WPF